# How do I effectively import a prefab in unity with scripts and colliders still attactched

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a car prefab that I need to import from one project to another, but I cannot do this because the only thing it allows me to import is the wheel meshes.so I can export everything just fine, but when I try to import it to the other project, it will give me the option to select what parts I want to import, and I cannot select them, because everything but the wheel meshes will be unable to be selected

Comment: It’s been a while but make a unity package of the car and it should take all it needs

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the main way to achieve this is by creating a package containing your prefabs, scripts and colliders. In Unity, packages allow you to distribute content quickly in a standardised way. Here are Unity's instructions regarding embedded package creation :

**Instructions:**

Follow these instructions if you want to create a custom package inside your project folder.

1. Open the Unity Hub, and create an empty project on your computer. You can also use an existing project on your computer, and embed the package under your project or install the package from a local folder. However, starting with a new project makes the package contents less prone to errors.
2. Using your computer’s file manager (for example the Windows File Explorer or the macOS Finder), navigate to your project folder and locate the Packages subfolder.
3. Create a new subfolder for your package inside the Packages folder using a name that matches the package name. For example, if your package is called com.example.mypackage, the subfolder should also be called com.example.mypackage.
   **Note:** This is particularly important if your package contains assets, because the AssetDatabase looks for an asset path that matches Packages//Assets, regardless of what the actual folder is called.
4. Open your preferred text editor and create a JSON file called package.json.
5. Save it under the new package root folder you created.
6. Fill out all required and recommended fields in the package manifest (package.json) file. The two following properties are the only required properties as of Unity 2022.2 (mode details can be [found here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/upm-manifestPkg.html)) :

   ```
   {"name":"PackageName",
   "version":"0.0.0"}
   ```
7. When you reopen Unity, the new package appears in the Package Manager window and in the Project window, where you can view and modify the package contents. If you select the package.json file in the Project window, you can also modify its contents directly in the Inspector
   window.

**Documentation:**

Here is a link to the Unity docs regarding packages : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html